# Open web address in html object with out reloading new window

Tags: html, forms, http, object

I am wondering if anyone out there would be willing to tell me how I could use the html form text box I have on my apache server to open a web address entered into my text box on my html object below it.  I have a problem with iframes on my server so i'd rather use an object.  Any help would be wonderful!

Thanks Carl.

Comment: What are the problems with Iframes on your server? They would do a better job then text boxes.

Comment: Well no I want to enter a web address in a text box and have it open in a html object.  I have tried iframes before and my server dosen't seem to take to them

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

Whenever you have text in your input field, have a button to submit and call the function that will load html data into your div that I called includeContent for the purpose of this example.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function() {
$("#includeContent").load("b.html"); 
}); 
</script> 
</head>

<body>
 <div id="includeContent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok so how would i implement this. I'm trying different ways and its still just opening a new tab and not actually a object

Comment: So create your text field with a button. Whenever the button is clicked just call the function mentioned above that will load any html page within a DIV, rather than a new tab/window.